# Trying to rotate a point around another point and it's not working

Tags: mathematics, rotation

I am trying to make a function to rotate a point around another point. My maths are very rusty but i did some research and i just dont understand why my function is not working.

```java
public void rotatePoint(int pX,int pY,int angle) {
    int newX = 0, newY = 0; 
    int centerX = 400, centerY = 300;

    angle *= Math.PI / 180; // convert angle from deg to rad

    double rotatedX = Math.cos(angle)*(pX-centerX)-Math.sin(angle)*(pY-centerY) + centerX;
    double rotatedY = Math.sin(angle) * (pX-centerX) + Math.cos(angle) * (pY-centerY) + centerY;

    newX = (int)Math.round(rotatedX);
    newY = (int)Math.round(rotatedY);
}
```

On the image i just provide my original point is in grey. After a rotation of 90 or 180deg i would expect the point to arrive where the green ones are. They arrive where the red points are.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your red points are rotated something like 60 degrees from your starting point, rather than the full 90 you expected. Let's investigate why that could be...

```
angle *= Math.PI / 180;
```

As we substitute in an initial value of 90 for `angle`, this translates to...

```
angle = angle * 3.141592653589 / 180.0
angle = 90 * 0.01745329251
angle = 1.57079632679
```

But wait, our `angle` variable is an integer, so we have to truncate to convert this floating point intermediate to an integer value we can store in this variable:

```
angle = 1 radian
```

Or about 57 degrees, which matches up to what we're seeing in your graph.

So, use a float or double as your intermediate:

```
double radianAngle = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
```

And compute your sine and cosine ratios off of this fractional intermediate instead.

Comment: Tks!! i will try that tomorrow and give feedback but it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Its working, big tks again!